# Call CMS Block with Category name as Identifier

Tags: magento2, template, phtml

The goal is to call a static cms block at the bottom of the category page, with block identifier == category name (so that I can make a block in the admin backend for every category).

So I first thought of just adding a static cms block in the catalog_category.xml in my theme, but I think it is not possible to call the category name inside of the xml (or is it?)

Second try was to call a phtml template in the xml file. In the phtml teplate, I just call a static block with the name of the category. Unfortunately, I can't get the XML to work :/

This is what I added to **MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

```
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.bottom" template="Magento_Catalog::category/bottom.phtml"/>
```

And in the template directory under category, I added the bottom.phtml. But when I open a category now, it says "File path is forbidden for security reasons".

So I tried to just call a template that is already there (the description.phtml), but that did not work either.

Now it gets strange: I tried to override the description.phtml in my theme, just to test if I got the paths right. The result was that the description in the frontend just disappeard, no matter what I wrote in the file - even if I just copied the original file to the override file. I just can't understand why...

Can anyone help?

Thanks, Valentin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a small extension for this requirement.

**First, create a block class `View.php` which generates  for bottom cms section**
which should be located at `app/code/Parkourstore/Catalog/Block/Category`

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by Amit Bera.
 * User: Amit Kumar Bera
 * Email: dev.amitbera@gmail.com
 * Date: 13-06-2018
 * Time: 09:04
 */

namespace Parkourstore\Catalog\Block\Category;


class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    public  function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCmsBlockBottomHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->getData('cms_block_bottom_html')) {
            $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class
            )->setBlockId(
                $this->getCurrentCategory()->getName()
            )->toHtml();
            $this->setData('cms_block_bottom_html', $html);
        }
        return $this->getData('cms_block_bottom_html');
    }
}
```

- Second, you have create a template file for this block at
  `app/code/Parkourstore/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/bottom-cms.phtml`

```
 <?= $block->getCmsBlockBottomHtml() ?>
```

- 3rd you have to  call this block using layout so create
  `catalog_category_view.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content.bottom">
             <block class="{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms.bottom" template="{VendorName}_{ModuleName}::category/bottom-cms.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
    </body> 
</page>
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, I get an two exceptions: `
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Parkourstore\Catalog\Block\Category\View
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Parkourstore\Catalog\Block\Category\View does not exist`.  Here is a screenshot how I build the module, maybe wrong paths? http://prntscr.com/junklq

Comment: And I added the XML in my theme (Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml)

Comment: Location seems ok from screesnhot. But might be block class name is wrong, Please check updated post.

Comment: Stupid me forgot to copy the opening php tag >< Thank you so much! Works now! I changed it to 'setBlockId(
                "cat-bottom-" . $this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()
            )->toHtml();'  and it works perfectly!

Comment: How to add cms block using custom module instead of adding cms block from magento admin backend https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/330082/57334