# How to get a custom CMS block on Product page through attributes

Tags: magento2, product

I would like to do the following:
 
- Have a two custom product attributes
- Attribute One should be called as a static CMS block (e.g. if I type in "test123" in the product configuration, Magento should load the custom block with the ID "test123" and display it on the product page
- Attribute 2 should just be displayed. If I type in "test123" I just want it to appear as "test123" on the product page

What I tried to do is edit this code and apply it on product pages, but it created an error that didn't even go away when I uninstalled the module and I had to run a backup.. [Call CMS Block with Category name as Identifier](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/229695/call-cms-block-with-category-name-as-identifier)

Does anyone know how to do that or how to correctly edit the code I was using?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please share code in question which you used in product view page.

Comment: I posted a link in the question @PrincePatel

Comment: The link is for the category page. Please update question with code which you used for product page

Comment: I uninstalled the plugin and run a backup -> I don't have the code anymore. But basically, I changed "category" to "configurable-product", changed the extensions names and the ID the block was called with. I did not expect it to work, just expected to be able to experiment with it, but did not happen @PrincePatel